# Umbraco backoffice no sections

Tags: umbraco7

I have several sites running on Umbraco 7.5.3 on my local ISS, for one of them I get empty section list when accessing back-office.

There are no javascript errors in console.

The issue is that request to

```
GET /umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Section/GetSections HTTP/1.1
```

returns empty array, while other websites returns sections as expected.
I can't find any documentation on this issue, or relevant source code to debug it for.

Could someone explain or give me a hint on what is happening and how that array is filled out.

I've removed cache, cookies, tried incognito, different browsers, reinstalling Umbraco.

Comment: I have no experience with this problem, but could you check if trees.config (in Config directory) is filled?

Answer (score 0):

In your config folder, check that the /config/applications.config and /config/trees.config files have contents. I have seen it happen occasionally where these files get set to empty for some reason, which causes trees to be empty.

If they're empty, delete them and touch the web.config file to restart the app, and the files should get rebuilt.

Comment: I've checked these files, they are all good. The problem was somewhere inside database, I had to rollback the db, changes in git and do the same thing over, it worked...